# Write file names in to a file

Tags: shell, files

In a directory I have `X.txt`,`Y.txt`,`Z.txt` files. I want to move these filenames into a single file like below:

```
Out_file.txt
X.txt
Y.txt
Z.txt
```

Any unix command to achieve this?

Comment: Basic redirect. You know what `ls` does, I suppose. Try `ls > list.dat` or, if there are other files, `ls *.txt > list.dat`.

Answer (score 16):

```
ls >> Out_file.txt
```

When you are in concerned folder of course...

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple step, you'd just need to redirect the output of 'ls' into a file.

```
ls -1 >> file.txt
```

Comment: In all `ls` implementations I've seen, `ls` detects when its STDOUT is not to a terminal and uses the `-1` style output automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to solve this problem is as follow:

```
ls | tee Out_File.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `Out_file.txt` to contain a sorted list of the name of all the non-hidden files ending in `.txt` without including `Out_file.txt` if it wasn't there beforehand, you can do:

```
sh -c 'ls -d -- "$@" > Out_file.txt' sh *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` strikes me as a good choice for the OP's question, and for many similar objectives:

- Recursion and the relative file specification are *"free"* with `find`, so this command will gather a list of all `.txt` files at or below the user's current dir, and redirect the list to `Out_file.txt`:

  ```bsh
  find -name \*.txt > Out_file.txt
  ```

  The output will be of the form `./filename.txt`, one file per line.
- If only the bare filename is wanted in the output (no directory specs), `find` (*most* versions) has a built-in `printf` option:

  ```bsh
  find -name \*.txt -printf "%f\n" > Out_file.txt
  ```

  The output will be of the form `filename.txt`, one file per line.
- If full recursion isn't wanted (or if *"limited recursion"* is needed), the `maxdepth` option is available:

  ```bsh
  find -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt -printf "%f\n" > Out_file.txt
  ```

  This output will be in the same form as many of the other answers here, but won't necessarily be sorted in alphabetical order. If alphabetical order is needed, the `find` output may be piped through `sort`:

  ```bsh
  find -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt -printf "%f\n" | sort > Out_file.txt
  ```

  ```
  X.txt  
  Y.txt  
  Z.txt
  ```
- The version I find most useful is this:

  ```bsh
  find $(pwd) -name \*.mp3 > FullPlaylist.txt
  ```

  I can create a full playlist of (e.g. mp3-encoded) music files that can be used with `mpg321`

Comment: `find` uses directory order, not alphabetical order. If you create `c`, `a`, and `b` in a newly made directory, `ls` will give you `a`, `b`,  `c` whereas `find` is more likely to produce `c`, `a`, `b`

Comment: Agreed... but as I read the OP's question, order wasn't specified as a requirement. Still, if you want alphabetical order, that can be arranged by piping thru `sort` before redirecting to output file. This is just my £0.02 worth; as indicated, my usage is mostly recursive & creating "play lists", but it occurred to me `find` might be useful to some who read this. Sorry if you disagree.

Comment: I don't disagree with your solution. I'm merely pointing out that it won't necessarily be sorted alphanumerically

Answer (score 0):

If you want file names of text files,

```
ls *.txt > file_name_output.text
```

If you want to get file contents together,

```
cat *.txt > file_content_output.text
```

Comment: What about names of directories?

Comment: Oh - got it. `ls -d */`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `tar -cf file.tar X.txt Y.txt Z.txt` 
This will create file.tar you can run the below command to see the output

`vim file.tar`

eg:

`tar -cf file.tar X.txt Y.txt Z.txt`

```
    vim file.tar
    " tar.vim version v29
    " Browsing tarfile /root/file.tar
    " Select a file with cursor and press ENTER  
    X.txt   
    Y.txt 
    Z.txt
```

Shown is the out from my system, means it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ls | tee -a Out_file.txt`

Explanation:

1. ls -> List directory contents
2. | ->   A  pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators | or |&.

3. tee -> Read from standard input and write to standard output and files
4. -a -> Append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite

Answer (score -1):

With all the "ls" related solutions there is a great chance of including format-related gibberish to the text file.

"dir -1 > file.txt" command gives you a single column with the names of all the files and folders in that directory straight away.

Answer (score -1):

`ls | tr '\n' '\n' >filename.txt`

This can save file names of the directory in the file.

Comment: The `tr` command that you pipe the output of `ls` through accomplishes exactly nothing. Please provide some explanation to your solution.